# touchesMoved QuartzDemo application

Tags: iphone, pdf

I am modifying the QuartzDemo application to include swipe detection while UIView is active (a PDF page being displayed in it via Quartz).

This will not work, the event never gets to the `QuartzView.m` because it sits under scrollview?

`touchesBegan:` works fine and I can use single tap.

How can I go about with catching touchesMoved while PDF page is being displayed?

I need a simple example with code that does nothing on `touchesMoved:`, I'll build up on that later.

Please keep in mind that I still want to use the UIScrollview as it is and show PDF content based on selection in that scrollview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by implementing touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded in QuartzView.m.

I also added this in QuartzViewController.m:

```
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
scrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;
```

Works like I wanted it to :)